# How to append elements of array to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having trouble with adding elements to my HTML.  I think my issue lies in my understanding of HTML but I'm not really sure.  Here is my Javascript:

```
<div class="console">
    <div id="console_data">
        <p class="console_text"> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me explain what this is doing, or at least what I'm trying to do.  The console class creates just a black rectangle, and it's gonna have some white text in it, which is what console_text is for.  Here is my javascript to append things to console_data:

```
var consoleData = ["Hello World"]
var consoleInfo = document.getElementById('console_data')

for (var i = 0; i < consoleData; i++) {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a')
    var value = consoleData[i]
    anchor.href = value
    consoleInfo.appendChild(anchor)
}
```

I was under the impression this would append the text Hello World inside of the black box I created, but it's just showing the empty black box.  Is my console_data tag even necessary? Where should I be trying to append my data to?

Comment: `i < consoleData` should be `i < consoleData.length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking whether `i` is smaller than `consoleData`'s length, since you are iterating through it:

```js
var consoleData = ["Hello World"]
var consoleInfo = document.getElementById('console_data')

for (var i = 0; i < consoleData.length; i++) {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a')
    var value = consoleData[i]
    anchor.href = value
    anchor.innerHTML = value
    consoleInfo.appendChild(anchor)
}
```

```html
<div class="console">
    <div id="console_data">
        <p class="console_text"> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I feel dumb for missing that, but also it still does not work after making that change, as well as adding the anchor.innerHTML line.

Comment: @emperorcrimson How's it not working? It's working fine in the snippet.

Comment: I agree this does work, I was working simultaneous to @Spectric on this using jsfiddle and arrived at almost the exact same solution. 

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/condorhauck/5ct3vo9j/20)

Comment: I'm not sure.  I have exactly the same thing, but on my machine it's showing up as a blank black box.  It's not like its black text on a black background either because I tried to highlight it with my cursor and it really is blank.   Genuinely really confused now.   I even deleted what I had and copied in your comment and still nothing.

Comment: Check your css.  Here is what I used in the fiddle 

#console_data 
{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: terminal, courier, monospace;
  padding: 5px, 25px;
}

Comment: Still not showing up even after using exactly what you have.  I thought that I wasn't using my files correctly but my html file has both a link to my css file and a script tag for my js file so I'm not sure exactly what's going on.  I had hard coded some text earlier and that showed up so really not sure which piece is missing.

Comment: I solved it.  I needed to add my script tag at the end of my HTML document, so that it loaded last.  Silly mistake.

Comment: Another small issue though, could anyone explain as to why the text is showing up as a hyperlink rather than just text? Clicking the link says Cannot GET

Comment: Nvm, needed to change a to p.  Thread done.

Comment: @emperorcrimson *'showing up as a hyperlink rather than just text"* - because it's an anchor tag. Hence the `"a"` when you create the element.